# My File accdb is missing but Data still can entry

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, ms-access, oledb

In my C# apps "MyApps.Exe", i use Provider Microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0 to access my accdb file..

I set data source with

```
Data Source="+Application.StartupPath+"\\databaseFile.accdb
```

So my apps will read the `databaseFile.accdb` in the same folder with Exe file. The folder name is `CurrentFolder`.

I have compile my apps and install it in : "C:\Program Files(x86)\CurrentFolder"

Peculiarities occur, when file "databaseFile.accdb" has been deleted from folder "CurrentFolder".

When I run "MyApps.exe", then login entry username and password, and then Entry ,read data. The Apps is still running.

This should not happen because "databaseFile.accdb" has been deleted.

Why it can happen? I am confused for this happen.
Anyone can explain this ? why my Apss still can access/read database.accdb
eventough the database was deleted.

Thanks in advance.

**--Addition Information --**
Before, i share folder "C:\Program Files(x86)\CurrentFolder" to network. and add Permissions to Everyone Full Control.

I hope this information can help our problem analysis.

Here source code my **connection.cs**

```
        public Connection()
                {
                    try
                    {
                    alamat = "Provider=Microsoft.ace.Oledb.12.0; Data Source="+Application.StartupPath+"\\databaseFile.accdb";

                      koneksi = new OleDbConnection(alamat);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                    }
                }

        public static Connection GetInstance(){
                    if(Connection.connection == null){
                        Connection.connection = new Connection();
                    }

                    return Connection.connection;
                }

        //this is for check wether the file databaseFile.accdb is exist in that folder
         public int cekDb(string locasi)
                {
                    int a=0;
                    if (File.Exists(locasi))
                    {
                         a = 1;
                    }
                    return a;
                }
             public int CekLogin(string user,string pass)
                    {
                        koneksi.Close(); 
                        koneksi.Open();
                        perintah = new OleDbCommand("select * from [user] where username = '" + user + "' and password = '" + pass + "';", koneksi);
                        myReader = perintah.ExecuteReader();
                        int count = 0;
                        while (myReader.Read())
                        {
                            leveluser = myReader["type"].ToString();
                            count++;
                        }
                        koneksi.Close(); 
                        return count;
                    }
```

**In my login.cs**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    if (textBox1.Text == "" || textBox2.Text == "")
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Please Fill your Username or Password");
                        textBox1.Focus();
                    }
                    else
                    {

                          if(connection.cekDb(Application.StartupPath+"\\databaseFile.accdb")==1){

                            int cek = connection.CekLogin(textBox1.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "''"), textBox2.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "''"));

                            if (cek != 0)
                            {
                             DashBoard entry = new DashBoard();

                                entry.Show();
                                UseWaitCursor = false;
                            }
                            else if (cek == 0)
                            {
                                //  konek.Disconnect();
                                MessageBox.Show("Please Check your username and password !!");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show(cek.ToString());
                            }
                        }
                         else
                        {

                            MessageBox.Show("File DatabaseFile.accdb Not Found !!");
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: It probably exists somewhere else. In any case, `C:\Program Files(x86)\` is in _no way_ a place to store documents - as a the database file is.

Comment: Really, there's no such thing as reading data from a non-existent database. Either you're not reading data from the database, or the database exists. You're not providing us with enough information to replicate your error.

Comment: @gustav : i have search in my Windows ..in Drive C:\ and Drive D:\ but i didn't get result where is the file databaseFile.accdb exist..But the Apps stil can login, read and entry data.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth ..I Have add an information..that i have shared the folder befor and add Permision to everyone with Full Control Permision.

Comment: Which folder has MyApps.exe?  How do you know it has read data?  Do you have an error catch.  Please show the code that opens the database.

Comment: http://www.voidtools.com/ is very useful to find misplaced files, if you know the file name.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock in Folder "C:\Program Files(x86)\CurrentFolder"..it is same folder with "databaseFile.accdb"..
C:\Program Files(x86)\CurrentFolder
    - MyApps.exe
    - databaseFile.accdb (But now this file has been deleted and MyApps stil can login,read,entry and edit data.)

Comment: @Andre I have search in all My Drive ..in C:\ and in D:\ but i didn't find my databaseFile.accdb..

Comment: @ZAJ can you answer my other comments please?

Comment: @JonathanWillcock I'm sorry for late..i have add Source code in file connection.cs and login.cs..Thanks for your help before.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock i know it has read data when MyApps.exe can Login..because login is read username and password in databaseFile.accdb

Comment: @ZAJ Did you install with ClickOnce?

Comment: @JonathanWillcock no i use advanced installer to compile it.

Comment: @all..is it possible file databaseFile.accdb saved in temporary windows? -_-..but i have search it and still not found ..i search with *.acccdb

Comment: @ZAJ Does your Network have the user documents folder on a network drive?

Comment: @JonathanWillcock Yes it have..

Comment: Have you looked in the network\documents\username folder?

Comment: Yes But the databaseFile.accdb not found at there..I shared my Folder  "C:\Program Files(x86)\CurrentFolder" to network..

Comment: Perhaps it is in "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\..."?

Comment: @GordThompson Many Thanks..i have found the databaseFile.accdb in that folder..why it can happen? how to prevent it.